# What is this sci-fi film involving a time/teleportation machine and a boy in a spacesuit

Tags: story-identification

- There was a time-machine (or teleportation machine) in a spherical geodesic shape, made of metal with large panels, it was dark grey or dark blue.
- A pilot used the machine while wearing a spacesuit, the machine shook violently when activated. The pilot was a white american man.
- He was either transformed into the body of a child or replaced with a child, perhaps his younger self, early teenage years. It might be the case that the spacesuit was lost and an unrelated child found it.
- The child walks home down a sidewalk in the oversized spacesuit; This was in a suburb somewhere with a hedgerow on the side of the sidewalk
- The spacesuit had a very large rim around the neck, and correspondingly large hemispherical helmet, it was very baggy on the child.
- I think after the machine's operation the pilot's coworkers started searching for him.

I think I watched this in the late 90s or early 00s on British television, although I'm quite sure it was an American movie, probably from the 90s.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Thanks, @Valorum, I've added some more details.

Comment: How did he get out of the facility if he had co-workers?

Comment: That's a good question and I'm not sure I remember the answer. I suspect he was transported away by the machine without the possibility of his coworkers intervening.

Keep asking questions and perhaps we'll come up with an original plot for a movie!

Comment: The bluish geodesic sphere piloted by a person in a spacesuit makes me think of the TV series Seven Days, but I don't know if any of the episodes match in the other particulars.

Comment: @starpilotsix could you add this as an answer please! I recognised the sphere immediately. Looks like I'll have to run through the episodes to find the exact one I'm remembering!

Comment: From the synopsis on Wikipedia it looks as though S01E11 could be it: "After the backstep however, Parker regresses to a childlike state"

Comment: Indeed, the child walking in the baggy spacesuit can be seen at 26:20 in that episode.

Comment: Hah, weird - doing a rewatch of this _awesome_ show just at the moment and caught this episode literally last night! I highly recommend Seven Days to everybody.

Comment: @Valorum That's the mechanic of the show. Parker "launches" in the device and reappears somewhere else, seven days ago. In this instance, the transport went wrong, and regressed his _mind_ to a childlike state. The kid wearing the spacesuit wasn't actually him though.

Comment: Just came to say I immediately thought of the Dr Who episode The Impossible Astronaut :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This seems to be an episode of the 1998-2001 TV series [Seven Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Days_(TV_series)), in which a government project exists that can send someone back in time, but only seven days.

The sphere you remember is the Backstep Sphere (or Chronosphere) and as you can see it matches the description:

[image: Backstep Sphere, a geodesic sphere in deep blue]

The main time traveller routinely uses a space suit in his journeys... the sphere also shakes a great deal and requires piloting talent:

[image: Headshot of Cmdr Parker in a space suit]

Although the sphere normally projects Frank back seven days, at which point everything sent back in time (the sphere, the pilot, the astronauts) disappear from where they were in the past and are replaced by the new versions.  As such, his co-workers typically only learn a backstep has occurred when he and the sphere disappear, and then immediately start looking for him because they know something big must be about to happen.

Of course, being an episodic TV show, things frequently go wrong in unusual ways that mess with the formula.  The specific events you remember seem to be from S01E11, "HAARP Attack" in which Frank is regressed to a childlike state after travelling back.

You can see in this video the journey, and him meeting a child in the playground immediately after arriving.  His co-workers (searching the area) later (at approximately 26 minutes into the video) find the child with the over-sized-for-him spacesuit, who took it after Frank abandoned it:

Comment: By the way, as E Lee Zimmerman correctly identified, [this series was recently (_finally_) released on DVD](https://www.visualentertainment.tv/products/7-days-the-complete-collection-7108?variant=13635528589417). Fans of this show may be interested to know that.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Wow. Now there's an incredibly delayed DVD release. I think I remember back in 2001 wondering if it wasn't renewed due to there being no good way to deal with the dissonance of the real 9/11 (since the show always dealt with heading off such disasters), but Wikipedia & [other sources](http://nitcentral.philfarrand.com/discus/messages/489/489.html?1316331400) indicate it was already canceled for unrelated reasons, [sparing it](http://nitcentral.philfarrand.com/discus/messages/489/17109.html?1282614632), like newspaper-from-future "Early Edition", from dealing with 9/11

Comment: @JacobC. Indeed! It was actually cancelled mostly due to personality clashes behind the scenes, but its niche nature left it in limbo until literally this year, much to my own chagrin. I asked Scott Gilman (the musical composer) a few years back whether a formal soundtrack might ever be forthcoming and sadly (but not surprisingly) he was unable to say anything that the rights holders were not saying: my remote hope is that now that a DVD has been released, _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ that may be more likely, but as VIE is well-known for official-but-third-party DVD salvations I don't think the DVD release speaks to the likelihood of an accompanying soundtrack release.